# Serving static content returns null ModelAndView

Tags: java, spring-boot

We are running a spring boot application on top of an angular app. In our setup, we have subclassed the `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` to map routes from `/app/**`, `/assets/**` to `/angular-app/app/` and `/angular-app/assets/` respectively. I am having trouble routing `/error` to return the page located in `/angular-app/error.html`. From what I understand, accomplishing this should be done by implementing the `InternalResourceViewResolver`.

I ran the app with trace enabled and it seemed as if the GET request to `/angular-app/error.html` is returning a null model and view. I fear that we are disabling some functionality by subclassing `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` which is necessary to get this running like it would normally and serving content from `/public` or `/static`

The configuration code is as follows.

```
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    private static Logger log =     Logger.getLogger(WebMvcConfiguration.class);

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver getViewResolver() {
        log.info("configured view resolver");
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new     InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/angular-app/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".html");
        return resolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("forward:/index.html");
        registry.addViewController("/login/no-op").setViewName("forward:/no-op.html");
        registry.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/app/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/angular-app/app/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/assets/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/angular-app/assets/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/fonts/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/angular-app/fonts/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/maps/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/angular-app/maps/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/scripts/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/angular-app/scripts/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/styles/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/angular-app/styles/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/index.html").addResourceLocations("classpath:/angular-app/index.html");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/no-op.html").addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/no-op.html");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/angular-app/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/css/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/css/");
    }

    @Override
    public void addArgumentResolvers(List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> argumentResolvers) {
        argumentResolvers.add(new AuthenticationPrincipalArgumentResolver());
    }
}
```

and after a request, I see a log that state that the request was routed to the correct location.

`[INFO]::[2016-07-12 12:08:11.979 PM]::[ity.common.filter.LoggerFilter] <<<[GET][maadmin@maestroqa.com][UNKNOWN_IP]::/angular-app/error.html`

I've attempted to use `setAlwaysUseFullPath` to `true` which yielded the same results.

Please let me know if I can provide any more information.

Comment: Are you using JSPs? how are you deploying your application? Are you aware of the JSP support limitations? http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-jsp-limitations

Comment: We are just using html pages, no JSP's. The angular app is served by the application and communicates back to the API via jQuery.

Comment: where is the `angular-app` folder located in your project structure?